# How to Handle Rename Event in npm Chokidar

Tags: node.js, electron, node.js-fs, chokidar

When I **renamed** a file/folder in windows where **chokidar** is watching Parent Directory, then Add and unlink events are getting triggered  which is not expected. So help me on this how to handle the Rename of Folder or File preventing the** **add and unlink events**** to be triggered

I am expecting a solution from community so as  to bypass the add or unlink events and  only rename the folder/file in windows